# Rails rake task invoke error catching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a rails code snippet that does a rake file from a model.

```
Rake.application.rake_require '../../lib/tasks/master_load'
fork do
  results = capture_stdout {Rake.application['db:seed:excel:to_yaml'].invoke}
end
```

capture_stdout is for printing out the logs

```
def self.capture_stdout
    s = StringIO.new
    oldstdout = $stdout
    $stdout = s
    yield
    s.string
    Rails.logger.info "#{s.string}"
  ensure
    $stdout = oldstdout
end
```

it works, but when the rake encounters error and fails.
it fails silently.
is there a way to know if error has occured and perhaps get the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rescue to catch and handle error

```
def self.capture_stdout
    s = StringIO.new
    oldstdout = $stdout
    $stdout = s
    yield
    s.string
    Rails.logger.info "#{s.string}"
  rescue Exception => e
    # handle e - exception object 
  ensure
    $stdout = oldstdout
  end
```

Ensure in this case silently makes action after exception handling